# Python (Alternate two messages)

Tags: python

I have some code, and my goal is to make it so that when left button is clicked it will post text saying "Programming is fun!" and when it is pressed again, it will change that text to "It is fun to program", my idea was to make x = 0 if I wanted the first statement, and x = 1 if I wanted the second statement, but it keeps saying x is not defined, I've tried returning x but it simply won't... I've tried a variety of different methods but I can't figure it out. Thoughts? I'd like an alternative method to this, because I'm not sure that mine will work.

```
def text():
pf = Label(window2,text="Programming is fun")
pf.pack()
x = 0

def text2():
    fp = Label(window2,text="It is fun to program")
    fp.pack()
    x = 1

def bt(event):
    if x == 0:
        text()
    elif x == 1:
        text2()

window2 = Tk()
window2.geometry("500x500")
```

Comment: The code as posted starts with a SyntaxError.   Please edit until it constitutes a proper MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Then post the traceback produced by the code you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this below, the down low is that it's creating the text through that function, and then it's rebinding the key to do other function and then that function deletes previous text, creates the new text and then rebinds to the previous function, and the cycle continues. Here's the code.

```
def text(event):
    global pf
    fp.pack_forget()
    pf = Label(window2,text="Programming is fun")
    pf.pack()
    window2.bind("<Button-1>", text2)

def text2(event):
    global fp
    pf.pack_forget()
    fp = Label(window2,text="It is fun to program")
    fp.pack()
    window2.bind("<Button-1>", text)

window2 = Tk()
window2.geometry("500x500")

pf = Label(window2,text="Programming is fun")
fp = Label(window2,text="It is fun to program")

window2.bind("<Button-1>", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in the scope of your functions, the variable `x` is indeed undefined.

An example:

```
height = 5

def some_function():
    # code here can not access height just like that
```

When you want to access variables in functions, you generally have three options:

1) Put your code in a class instead. This requires some understanding of [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), and if you're a beginner this might not be the best choice for you

2) Pass the variable as an argument to the function and add it to the function's parameter list, for example like this:

```
def my_function(height):
    # here height can be used
```

And when calling the function:

```
height_of_bob = 2
my_function(height_of_bob)
```

3) Use a [global variable](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php). This is usually not necessary, and is [considered bad practice](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Global_variables) in general, but it will solve your problem just fine.

Comment: I tried global variable, but I think I'll need an alternative method to changing x, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you declaring it as global before using it? As in [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) example (make sure to read the whole thing)?

Comment: Thank you so much, but after steeping away for an hour I watched a movie, and thought of ways to do it in the back of my mind and I found something that worked. Posted below.....